# Is the wind-sound relationship similar to the DC - AC relationship?

Tags: waves

I am trying to understand the relationship between sound and wind. I think it is very similar to the DC - AC relationship. By wind and DC the particles (molecules/electrons) go to the same direction (except turbulence). By sound and AC the particles go back and forth. Is this really a good analogy, or am I misunderstanding something?

I had an interesting conversation in the comments which leaded to another question. Is it possible that by alternating current there are differences in the density of electrons depending on the coordinate parallel to the wire? Did somebody ever measure that?

Comment: I don't know how to answer, but newcomers to the field of electronics often are taught the basics of voltage and current flow in a wire by analogy to the pressure and flow of water in a pipe.  Note two differences between that analogy and yours:  (1) Air is a compressible fluid, but the usual analogy is to incompressible water.  (2) "in a pipe" is a different environment from the open, 3-D volume in which we usually encounter wind and sound.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, I though about this. Electric current can be modelled with a 2d flow, since it travels on the surface of the wire and on an axial slice of the wire probably the moving electrons are distributed evenly. On the other hand I guess non-laminar flows of fluids can be descibed with only 3d models. That's an obvious difference. What about compressibility? Does density of charge carriers change by AC or DC? Can they be considered as a compressible medium?